# list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python

I want to get the vector like: `v:[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`

Here is my code:

```
class VECTOR(list) :
     def _init_ (self,x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0,vec=[]) :
          list._init_(self,[float(x),float(y),float(z)])
          if vec :
               for i in [0,1,2] :
                    self[i] = vec[i]
```

But when I typed: `a = VECTOR(1,2,3)` 
it went wrong like this:

> TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

How can I dissolve it?

Comment: FWIW, don't inherit from builtin types. Composition ≫ inheritance here.

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that you've misspelled the name of the constructor. Replace `_init_` with `__init__`.

Here's the fixed code:

```
class VECTOR(list) :
     def __init__ (self,x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0,vec=[]) :
          list.__init__(self,[float(x),float(y),float(z)])
          if vec :
               for i in [0,1,2] :
                    self[i] = vec[i]

a = VECTOR(1,2,3)
print(a)
```

And the demonstration that it works:

```
 % python test.py
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I'd also like to give you a few additional comments:

- you should fix the coding style according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (that's a document every Python developer should read entirely);
- you can probably do something more Pythonic (thanks Benjamin);
- inheritance is not the only way to do that, you can also use an attribute to store the list and define the relevant methods (thanks Veedrac);
- you could also use `super` (see paddyg's answer);

**edit note:** I've added to this solution the relevant advises found in the comments.

Comment: This is the correct answer, people! Fixing the spelling of `__init__` gives you a class that actually accepts 3 separate arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters very true.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I don't understand why 2 people decided to downvote without any reason. For information, I have not down-voted the other answers even if I disagree.

Comment: @Maxime: simple misreading of the situation. I did down-vote the wrong answers though. :-)

Comment: Lots of people downvote tactically so it's possible it was that. This is definitely the correct answer and the comment about the coding style is also spot on. Adding to the actual answer - I think the code itself could be more Pythonic.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT
if you call using `super(VECTOR, list).__init__()` you don't need to pass self. <s>Also you need to pass 1,2,3 as a list [1,2,3]</s>